# AWS MySQL 5.6.40 - once overwhelmed, always overwhelmed

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, innodb

My MySQL DB is overwhelmed and I have no idea how to fix it :/

I can have normal load on my DB as long as I want, but as soon as the DB is overwhelmed once, it does not seem to get normal again until a DB restart. Even if I reduce load under the normal load. eg.:

- 100% load - DB works fine.
- 400% load - DB gets overwhelmed
- Back to 100% - DB is still overwhelmed
- Even 50% load - DB is still overwhelmed
- Restart DB -> 100% load - DB works fine.

Seems like something is triggered during the 400% load time which causes serious issues in MySQL. AWS metrics/logs do not look suspicious. 'show engine innodb status;' does not look suspicious neither. AWS CPU load: ~2%.

I now recognized that free memory is the reason for this issue. After free memory is empty and swap kicks in, MySQL starts slowing down. Any idea how to avoid this?

[image: Memory Metrics]

Comment: Turn on the slow query log, check `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, and make sure you're not using a bursting instance type (it'll start with `t`, like `t2.micro`).

Comment: I use 'SHOW PROCESSLIST;' for live monitoring. This is how I detected described behavior. I am using a r4.XXX instance. Same queries worked before without issues. During 'overwhelmed', those queries need longer without any obvious reason.

Comment: I would also examine I/O bottlenecks (i.e. I/O burst depleting I/O credits for non provisioned IOPS volumes). Also reduce `vm.swappiness` to 10 or lower in order to make the host less eager to use swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the issue was the AWS host system. I made a backup of the DB, and imported it in a new (AWS) DB. Now everything works great again.

Comment: Additional information request while you are HEALTHY. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.